# Understanding React Re-render Behavior and performance impact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been working with React for a while, but my understanding of its internal behavior, especially concerning re-rendering, isn't crystal clear.

From my research, I gathered:

> Re-render mainly occurs if there is:
>
> - Update in State
> - Update in prop
> - Re-rendering of the parent component

This was surprising. I'd assumed only the modified parts of the application would re-render. However, it seems like if a state within my component changes, ALL its child components re-render.

To delve deeper, I used the React profiler addon and set up this example:

```
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Test: NextPage = () => {
    const [pos, setPos] = useState({ test: false, test2: 'hass' });

    const onClick = () => {
        setPos(oldPos => {
            return { ...oldPos, test: true };
        });
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello React.</h1>
            <button onClick={onClick}>Hass</button>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
            <Test2 />
        </div>
    );
};
const Test2 = props => {
    const { pos } = props;
    console.log('RENDERED!');
    return <>Text</>;
};
export default Test;
```

Every time I click the button, both the console.log and the React profiler indicate that Test2 re-renders, irrespective of whether I pass pos to it.

While I'm aware useMemo can help prevent this, manually memorizing every child and descendant in larger components feels cumbersome.

Additionally, my entire application is encapsulated by Context Provider components:

```
<MyProvider>
   [remaining application]
</MyProvider>

// Definition
[...]
export const MyProvider: FC<MyProviderProps> = props => {
    const { children } = props;
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState<MyDataType[]>([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        // this updated the react state asynchronous with live data from my database
        const destroySupplierSnapshotHandler = registerDataListener(setMyData);
        return () => {
            if (destroySupplierSnapshotHandler) {
                destroySupplierSnapshotHandler();
            }
     
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <MyProviderContext.Provider
            value={{
                data,
                setData,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </MyProviderContext.Provider>
    );
};
[...]
```

I have two primary concerns:

1. If the context updates, will ALL child components re-render, even those unrelated to the updated data? This seems inefficient.
2. How can I ensure my applications remain performant? Should I minimize the use of React states in top-level functional components to reduce unnecessary re-renders?

I'm a bit perplexed and disheartened by this behavior in React. I'd appreciate any insights or corrections to my understanding. Thanks!